# Not getting the expected output (compound interest calculator)

Tags: c#

The expected output if I enter £100, 0.10, 10 (10 years) should be £259.37, but I'm getting 100.00000001000001

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace compound_interest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the amount of money that is being compounded! ");
            double P = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter the amount of interest (write it is 0.10 for 10% etc!! ");
            double MP2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter the number of years");
            double Y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double MP1 = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Pow(MP2, Y));
            double MP = (MP1) + 1;
            double A = (P) * (MP);
            Console.WriteLine(A);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: Tried to use decimal, had to changed to double because of the Math.Pow

Comment: Well this kind of imprecision is inherent in the `double` type. `decimal` is the way to address it, or you can multiply everything by 100 and use integer calculations instead.

Comment: Because i need it to square MP2 and the answer will be what i times A by to get the answer (the ammount of intrest)

Comment: I don't get what you expect from 0.1^10?  I suspect you want (1 + interest)^years * amount and not code you have... But that is not a programming question...

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this

```
 double MP1 = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Pow(MP2, Y));
```

Do this

```
 MP2 = 1 + MP2
```